# Lock Mouse Cursor

Tags: mouse

I'm using a USB Mouse ( OTG ) and I wanted to play some Counter Strike , But whenever the game starts the mouse cursor is still there and it wont lock and I can't shoot , Is there a fix to this or its a device issue? Thank you so much